# Custom Social Share Buttons with JavaScript (invalide href)

Tags: javascript

I tried this code but the url is invalid
how can I get the valide href of the current page?

error: href should represent a valid URL

my share button

```
<a class="facebook" target="_blank" onclick="fbshareCurrentPage()" href="">
facebook
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
```

my function js

```
function fbshareCurrentPage()
{
window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="+encodeURIComponent(document.URL))
}
```

I tried

```
document.URL
window.location.href
```

Comment: just change it in the HTML to `href="#"`

Comment: It can work as it is on JSFiddle in this link. https://jsfiddle.net/ufetqrv5/c

Comment: still not working :/

Comment: Can you try to visit actual URL with console.log URL and past it on browser address bar?

Comment: it opened in new target with that  utl :file:///C:/Users/somthing/Desktop/myProject/main%20my%20project/blog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found url start from `file://` is rejected.

I tested `http://aaa.html` can pass.

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Faaa.html
```

But `file://aaa.html` is rejected.

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=file%3A%2F%2Faaa.html
```

Answer (score 0):

'error: href should represent a valid URL' means `href` on `<a>` not a valid URL.

Comment: I got it , but how can I fix it